# How to distribute attributes with a random value to Turtles?

Tags: netlogo

I'm working on a social-interaction model, and I have encountered yet another obstacle which I am unable to solve. During the interaction between two kinds and turtles, "actors" and "statements", the actors receive either `opinion1` or `opinion2` which turns them either `red` or `green`.

When a statement with one of the two attributes is in the same patch with the actor as long as the actor hasn't received an opinion yet.

```
ask Akteure with [color = white and Audiosignal and not Kein_Empfangen] [
    if any? Statements with [color = green and Audiosignal] in-radius 10[
    set Information1 true
    set gut_1 true
    set color green
    ]
  ]
 ask Akteure with [color = white and Audiosignal and not Kein_Empfangen] [
    if any? Statements with [color = red and Audiosignal] in-radius 10[
      set Information2 true
      set schlecht_1 true
      set color red
```

While my code is working quite fine when it comes to a 100% chance of "infecting" the actor with a green or red statement. I wanted to implement a slider-based threshold value which represents the stubbornness of my actors.

My goal is to implement a random percentage-value for each actor (0-100%) combined with a slider for my threshold-level of stubbornness.

In other words: If the stubborn value of an actor is below the defined value via the slider, he will accept a new opinion, if the value is more than the value of the slider he won't accept the respective opinion.

I've tried constructs like the below, it's not working as intended. I don't get any error-report, but I also don't get the intended function.

```
ask Akteure with [color = white]
  [
    if stubbornness? <= Stubbornness-slider and any? Statements with [color = green] in-radius 3 [
  set color green
  set Information1 true
  ]
]
end


to-report stubbornness?
  report random 99
end
```

Can you maybe help me? Any more sophisticated ways to distribute random values to my turtles?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe there's an unintendet behaviour in the combination of the logical values? What does happen, if you only write `if stubbornness? <= Stubbornness-slider`? Does it then work as expected? And vice versa does work, if I understand you correclty? Maybe check, if you have to set paranthesis around the conditions: `if (stubbornness? <= Stubbornness-slider) and (any? Statements with [color = green] in-radius 3)`

Comment: A reproducible example would be ideal. Also, what is the unintended result? You don't get any error, but what happens to your agents that is not what you want?